# median of a rolling window, excluding zeros

Tags: python, pandas, median

when i try to find the rolling median of the following series, i get a list of NaNs.

I used:

```
b = a[a!=0].rolling(100).median()
```

a = actual data series (dataframe).  Has a bunch of zeros in it that i want to exclude when finding the median

b = rolling median

a[a!=0] gives me the following series.

`2017-10-05       NaN
2017-10-06 -0.001074
2017-10-09 -0.001804
2017-10-10       NaN
2017-10-11       NaN
2017-10-12 -0.001687
2017-10-13       NaN
2017-10-16       NaN
2017-10-17       NaN
2017-10-18       NaN
2017-10-19       NaN
2017-10-20       NaN
2017-10-23 -0.003972
2017-10-24       NaN
2017-10-25 -0.004663
2017-10-26       NaN
2017-10-27       NaN
2017-10-30 -0.003192
2017-10-31       NaN
2017-11-01       NaN
2017-11-02       NaN
2017-11-03       NaN
t2017-11-06       NaN
2017-11-07 -0.000189
2017-11-08       NaN
2017-11-09 -0.003762
2017-11-10 -0.000898
2017-11-13       NaN
2017-11-14 -0.002310`

the output is just a list of NaNs.

what am i doing wrong?
thank you!

Comment: So what is in `a` to start with?  What version of pandas?

Comment: a is a list of numbers with lots of zeros in between. it's a dataframe.

Comment: i'm using 0.20.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug in pandas.

Try this:

```
a[a!=0].rolling(window=100, center=False, min_periods=1).median()
```

Comment: this is very close.  good enough for me!  but the results are slightly different than what excel gives me.

Comment: Not a bug.  [**@Vaishali**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322255/2336654) explains it in her post.

Comment: I take some of what I said back.  I agree with @wim that there is a bug here with not skipping `np.nan`.  I can confirm the results with `a[a != 0].rolling(100).apply(np.nanmedian)`.  However, Vaishali's post is still worth looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Since a is Dataframe and not a Series, if you try to do indexing, you will get NaNs.

Consider this Series

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,10, 20), index = pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2017', periods = 20))
```

If you slice it, zeros are dropped

```
s[s!=0]
```

But for the dataframe, the same code will introduce the NaNs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, 20), index = pd.date_range(start = '01/01/2017', periods = 20))
```

You can handle this by specifying the column name while indexing

```
df[df[0] != 0] #df[0] being the column
```

Comment: @piRSquared However, `DataFrame.median` ignores nan by default, and since the rolling window just delegates to super for median, it should also ignore nan by default.  If you try to explicitly pass the kwarg `skipna=True`, it crashes somewhere in C code.  I still call that a bug, or at least a bad surprise...

Comment: @wim well that is a nasty surprise.  I'm checking now.  However, according to OP `np.nan` showed up unexpectedly.  And This post explains why.  Had OP filtered with a boolean series, they'd not have gotten `np.nan` and it should have worked.  That said, I'm checking what you've suggested because that sounds bad!

Comment: @piRSquared, I missed all the action on this last night and congratulations for 100K!